# I've been asked to develop a c# with DB with a "magnetic card", Where to start?

Tags: c#, sql, usb-drive

I'm used to work with the previous two (c#, mssql), but I don't know how does the magnetic card thing.

It's supposed to be an usb device and I suppose a little investigation concerning magnetic cards, but I can't accept the project and then realize I can't do it...

- I've been said that they don't have any kind of API to handle it, does c# provide one?
- I suppose that every magnetic card has some kind of encryption, doesn't it? If it does, I'm screwed.
- How to write IN the card? (Is the card that's written or the data stays on a server and the card only holds an Id?)
- Do you know of any tutorial you could provide?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the card reader, what kind of card reader is it?

Comment: There's too much in one question here. The first thing you need to do is find a magnetic card reader and it's drivers. It's all going to depend on what type of card(s) you want to read - we need that information as well.

Comment: @chibacity: Magnetic ones. Try to keep up ;)

Comment: @Jon Ah yes magnetic ones, silly me :)

Comment: @cularis There are different "kind" or readers? I didn't know

Comment: @cularis Don't close this, "where to start" question can't be less broad... I do not know about this.

Comment: Find out what reader they are using and get the driver/doc. We can't do much here to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go back to the potential customer and ask for a few more details - I'd guess that this will be much less stressful than you think it is and asking technical questions of the customer will help improve your credibility. Ask them:

- do they have any kind of system overview document
- have they selected the magnetic card (reader?) to use
- what sort of things are they expecting to store

---

The only "USB magnetic card" system I've ever coded against basically worked as a USB keyboard input - so using it was just a case of using a textbox.

Comment: 1-They do not, 2-They do, should I ask for it? Even when I don't know if I'm taking the project?, 3-A number, a decimal probably a price.

Answer (score 0):

First get more details on the card. Once you know the type and requirements you'll be able to ask better questions (more to the point) and make a decision.

Comment: @apacay, The hardware: brand, type, SDK, anything you can get your hands on. Requirements of the application: so you'll know what new things you will encounter. these will help you to ask very specific question here and to get answers too.